# CMake linking to external project

Tags: c++, cmake, external-project

I am new to cmake and want to use the following external project in my program. (https://github.com/mfontanini/cppkafka)
The idea is to download from git and build using cmake, which I have managed already. At the end of it, I am left with a .so file which I then have to link back to the main project. Any ideas on how I can achieve this ? Also, would like some suggestion on how to manage dependencies in a project with cmake that would possibly be carried forward to production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ADD_SUBDIRECTORY` to add the external project to your project. Then you can use the named tragets from this project while linking with `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ExternalProject of cmake](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/module/ExternalProject.html?highlight=externalproject#external-project-definition).

External project are downloaded in `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/third-party`

You can perform actions on them as target.